# How can a PhD student find a collaborator who might assist with programming in exchange for co-authorship?

Tags: publications, computer-science

I am a PhD student and since I am busy with my current projects, I have no time to implement a C# project for my paper.Also, I was looking for an intermediate C# programmer as a student job in my university ( Potsdam ). But, I could not find any one! So, I was wondering if you can tell me how could I find somebody to implement a C# program for me and be interested in participating and publishing a paper? is there any forum website or any solution in this situation?

Best,

Comment: Did you use the bulletin board in the faculty of computer science/software engineering? You could also try to find a [MATSE](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematisch-technischer_Softwareentwickler) and offer the position via job center.

Comment: And who is getting the credit? People will be wary to work for a random PhD student they do not know personally.

Comment: tried to make title more descriptive; feel free to edit further if any important nuance is missing (e.g., it wasn't clear to me whether you were offering payment as well as co-authorship).

Comment: Ask your professor to assign the task to an undergraduate student.

Comment: As a reminder, make sure you have a good handle on what a paper authorship entails.  It typically marks an intellectual contribution, and implementing a C# program you've already conceived probably doesn't qualify.  This route would probably better served by paying someone or through undergraduate workers/researchers in your school.  A more true collaboration is more easily found in fellow grad students which your advisor may be able to connect you to.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution would be finding someone locally. Contact the professors who teach advanced programming-oriented courses in your university (and also in Berlin, for instance, since the two cities are close) to see if they have someone to suggest among their past or present students.

Finding someone to do the work remotely seems more risky. It is difficult to train and mentor someone without meeting in person at least a few times.

And, in any case, when hiring a student for such a job, keep in mind that  there is always the risk that in the end this move will save you a *negative* amount of time, if you find the wrong person.

Comment: Thanks yes I understand. But I am also a programmer and have a little bit experience about how to deal with other programmers